# Saving java file in maven project fails

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss, jax-rs

when I try to save a java file in my project the following error occurs.

> Failed to (re)build the JAX-RS metamodel for projet TestApp
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

It only occurs when I create the default constructor so

```
public class Account {
    public Account () {}
}
```

gets the error, while

```
 public class Account {
 }
```

does not get it.

I was using the *jboss-javaee6-webapp-blank-archetype* to create my project

Comment: It's more an IDE-related question. You may want to say what you use and in which version (e.g.: Eclipse, NetBeans?).

Comment: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Kepler Release
Build id: 20130614-0229

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the failure by myself, there was no src/main/java folder created(I had my files in the resources folder), I reinstalled Eclipse, now the folder gets created and when I have my java files there, I don't get an error anymore.